# unable to click - div overlays another div

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, dom

I have two maps which are loaded via javascript into DOM (ngOnInit, I am using Angular 10).

The problem is that div of sk-map is overlaying on cz-map and if I want to hover/click on some region on the bottom right side of cz-map it is not possible, because sk-map div overlays on cz-map.
I can fix it - make cz-map with higher z-index, but there will the same issue, but in the sk-map (I am not able to select left top side of sk-map).

[image]

[image]

Comment: put both maps in the same image and create an [image map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Add_a_hit_map_on_top_of_an_image) and attach your js to that instead

Comment: Just thinking forward ... I don't believe that property `pointer-event: none` does help as it deactivates the whole div to the mouse, - but there are special events to svg's: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events. Same pessimism by using a css clip box (I SUPPOSE! it but I did not test it)? So, ... maybe you are able to merge both images to a single one? If ... it maybe could be the fastest solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can't really use divs in this situation.
Alternatives would be to use an svg which is fully vector.
Another suggestion is instead of being able to click the whole div, maybe use a good old fashioned image hotspot :)

Comment: But the .js file of each map is written to load inside some element using selector. So I add script to DOM, then set id of the element for load and call load() method. So anytime I have to put it into some element for load.